# Stop screen from dimming while on charger

Tags: screen-brightness

How can I stop the screen from dimming when my phone is charging? (the same thing the screen does when it's about to turn off).

Note that my screen already stays on, but it gets darker after an idle period.

Nexus 6P, stock Mashmallow.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this using Tasker. I created a Profile that, when plugged in, activates a task that sets the display timeout to a huge value. I accompanied it with an exit task that sets a normal-length display timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by adding a macro in macrodroid. Pretty simple and straight forward.

Like @spiffytech said when plugged in set the time out to never and when unplugged set the time out to 15sec.